# Lyx: exporting document in a "MathJax compatible" way

Tags: lyx, mathjax, export

When posting a question in math.SE, I like to write my questions in LyX and then export them to LaTeX. But there are several things that I have to do in the resulting LaTeX file in order to copy-paste the text successfully to the website, because some things are not compatible with mathjax. For example, LyX exports the displayed equations between `\[ ... \]`, and I would like it to export them between `$$ ... $$`.

Is there an easy way to do this?

Comment: You could use a text editor like notepad to find-and-replace occurances of `\[` with `$$`, and similarly replace `\]` with `$$`.

Comment: @DavidRobertson I know: but  that is precisely what I want to avoid, because this is just one example of incompatibility.