# Using Lyx to export documents in "MathJax" compatible way

Tags: lyx, mathjax

It's more comfortable writing my questions in LyX then copying the text as MathJax code and post it in MathExchange. 
the problem is that every time I need to do this copy and paste I need to delete certain things like
brackets and so on.

I have seen a similar question on Tex but there was no real solution for the problem:
[Lyx: exporting document in a "MathJax compatible" way](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/366614/lyx-exporting-document-in-a-mathjax-compatible-way)

is there any new way to solve this problem?

Comment: Welcome to tex.sx.  Ordinarily I would suggest checking the LyX website for information, but I've looked there and a search for "MathJax" in their documentation area doesn't turn up a single occurrence.  Not promising.

Comment: Hi @barbarabeeton, Actually I'm using now the suggestion that is in the similar question. turns out it's not that bad. Thanks!.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Again not the best solution but export to LaTeX (plain) and paste in a txt, and replace the [ and ] with $$. Here's a Python code that does it for you:

```
with open('C:/Users/ubald/Google Drive/CMU/LYX.txt', 'r') as file :
  filedata = file.read()

# Replace the target string
filedata = filedata.replace('\\[\n', '$$')
filedata = filedata.replace('\n\\]', '$$')

# Write the file out again
with open('C:/Users/ubald/Google Drive/CMU/LYX.txt', 'w') as file:
  file.write(filedata)
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!